# Rでのwebスクレイピング

Tags: r, web-scraping

Rでwebスクレイピングしたいと考えています。
抜き取りたい情報はM-１グランプリの情報で
(https://www.m-1gp.com/schedule/detail.html?id=539)におけるグループ名、コンビ名、結果の情報とコンビ名をクリックした先にある結成年、所属、前年度における結果等を抜き出そうと考えています。
初めのグループ名、コンビ名、結果の情報をtblとして抜き取ることはできたのですが、結成年等の情報を合わせて抜き出すことが出来ず苦戦しています。
複数のURLの情報を一つにまとめて抜き出す方法を教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: スクレイピング関連のモジュールや機能だけで1度にやろうとせず、それぞれのデータをいったん別々な2次元配列などに保持しておいて、あとから抽出・結合とかの加工をしてから、出来上がったものをcsvなどで保存するのが良いのでは？

Comment: 今出来ているところまでのコードを掲載いただくと回答者が回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: それぞれ抜き出す形に変更しようと思います